# How to get $i = ij + i^2$

Tags: ring-theory, idempotents

$A$ is a $k$-algebra where $k$ is a commutative ring.

Then for $e$ an idempotent in $A$ and $U,V$ submodules of $Ae$ s.t. $Ae = U\oplus V$, there is unique idempotents $i, j$ in $A$ s.t. $U = Ai, V= Aj, e = i+j.$

The beginning of the proof goes:

> Write $e = i + j $ for a unique $i \in U$ and $j \in V$ so we have $i = ij + i^2$. Then it is natural to conclude that $ij = 0, i^2 = i$ and $j^2 = j$.

Is there something off with the equality $i = ij + i^2$ as $e$ is not necessarily the unit of $A$ here? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @DietrichBurde. That's for the quaternions. That seems not to be the case here.

Comment: @md2perpe I am sorry for my joke. Of course, not quaternions now. The notation is just confusing.

Comment: @DietrichBurde. I agree. I first thought that it was about quaternions.

Comment: Can it be the case that it is actually assumed that $e$ is the unit element, and that it is then used that $e$ in fact is idempotent? Or might it be meant to use
$$i+j = e = e^2 = (i+j)^2 = i^2 + 2ij + j^2 = i + 2ij + j \implies ij = 0$$

Comment: nope, no assumption or implication that e is the unit. And the whole proof is based on this !

Comment: if we don't assume e is the unit, we don't have $i^2 = i$ in your line of reasoning, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $i \in U \subseteq Ae$, we can write $i=xe$ for some $x\in A$. Thus,
$$ i = xe = xe \cdot e = i(i+j).$$